# Delete everything after 4th period in string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, tcpdump

I'm trying to manipulate the output from **tcpdump** in python 2.7. What I'm trying to do is **remove** the **port portion** of the **IP** Address.

For example if the **input** string is

```
192.168.0.50.XXXX
```

How would I go about **deleting** everything after the **4th** period so the **output** would be

```
192.168.0.50
```

I've thought about doing something with the **length** of the string the only thing is port lengths can be anywhere from 1-5 digits in my example(0-9999).

The only thing I can think of is doing something with the # of periods as a **normal IP** only contains **3** and an IP with **Port** attached has **4**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rsplit()` for the cleanest or most simple route:

```
s = "192.168.0.50.XXXX"
s = s.rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

**Output**:

```
192.168.0.50
```

**[`rsplit()`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html)**

> Returns a list of strings after breaking the given string from right
>   side by the specified separator.

Comment: This solution worked for me and seemed to be the most concise solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
print('.'.join("192.168.0.50.XXXX".split('.')[:-1])) #or [:4], depending on what you want. To just remove the port, the -1 should work.
```

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into groups using the period as the separator. Take the first four groups and put them together again, using the same period as the separator:

```
ip = "192.168.0.50.XXXX"
".".join(ip.split(".")[:4])
#'192.168.0.50'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used **split** and **join** function do this.

Here is the step by step process:

```
ip="192.168.0.50.XXXX"
```

**Split** a string and **add** the data to a string array using a **defined separator.**

```
sp=ip.split(".")
#['192', '168', '0', '50', 'XXXX']
```

To select **everything** in the array except the **last** item

```
sp=sp[:-1]
#['192', '168', '0', '50']
```

Then join these elements using **join** function:

```
".".join(sp)
#'192.168.0.50'
```